# How to use startForeground with NotificationCompat.Builder?

Tags: android, service, android-notifications, foreground-service

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setContentTitle(description.getTitle())
                .setAutoCancel(false);
    NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notificationCompat=builder.build();
    notificationManager.notify(MY_ID,notificationCompat);
    startForeground(MY_ID,notificationCompat);
```

Used above code to run service in background. But when activity closed, service call onDestroy

Comment: "not working"? What is not working?

Comment: when display going off service calls onDestroy

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your service from `IntentService`, so it's working with separate thread and setOngoing true to your notification

```
builder.setOngoing(true)
```

After this user can't remove notification manually, and it supports the service in working condition.
And when activity closed your service will continue to work.

Comment: Its an media player service, playing in background

Comment: If i understand correctly, you mean that your service can't be extended from IntentService, because media player service extends from Service (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices) . So try to set setOngoing(true) to your notification, without extending from IntentService.